# Python: send executable binary file over smtp to gmail

Tags: python, gmail, executable, smtplib

how can i change the real file extension of executable binary to send that file through gmail smtp protocol (all in python).

Example: "binary" to "binary.jpg"

I'll try this:

```
import gzip, shutil
src = open('3c7983cb70e9630cc4ee2fe3e1fb16c2', 'rb')
dest = gzip.open('3c7983cb70e9630cc4ee2fe3e1fb16c2.gz.jpg', 'wb')
shutil.copyfileobj(src, dest)
```

but when I try to send it via gmail smtp happens to this:

```
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (552, '5.7.0 Our system detected an illegal attachment on your message. Please\n5.7.0 visit http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6590 to\n5.7.0 review our attachment guidelines. n18sm433437wbh.23')
```

Thancks in advance.

Comment: It's more traditional to name the file `.jpg.gz` rather than `.gz.jpg`.  I doubt that will fix your issue but it will make things more clear.  Furthermore, `gmail` probably inspects the contents of the binary file to determine if it's an executable regardless of its extension.

Comment: what makes you think gmail's engineers aren't smart enough to not be using Windows? On most OSes, the file extension is completely irrelevant and it would be stupid to rely on it to detect illegal attachments.

Comment: Gzipping a jpeg is a waste of resources and could increase the size of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Google's Policy, binary files are banned.

```
Gmail won't accept these types of files even if they are sent in a zipped
(.zip, .tar, .tgz, .taz, .z, .gz) format. If this type of message is sent to 
your Gmail address, it is bounced back to the sender automatically.
```

So Google is unzipping your file and most likely checking the file headers to determine the file type (not relying on the extension provided. To get around this you could try uploading it as a password protected ZIP file, since google wouldn't be able to crack it open to scan the contents, assuming they allow that.  Another option would be to encrypt the file before sending it, possibly even a very simple XOR encryption might be enough to get past the filtering. You would then need to decrypt upon retrieving the file.

Comment: What about file encoding to base64?

Comment: from 
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6590?hl=en

It isn't possible to send a password-protected zip file containing a zip file. Please de-compress all files or remove the password protection if possible.

Mac users, sending a zip file which also contains another zip file increases your chances of file corruption. We recommend that you de-compress all files first and create only one zip file.